# How does one look at the 'kernel log' in fedora linux

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, logging, fedora-12

I have just installed fedora 12 linux on my dell Gx2600 pc

every so often the pc hangs - screen goes blank & usb keyboard stops working.

Question:

is there a place were the kernel logs problems before it hangs

if so how do i access it.

Comment: Do you mean that when the screen saver puts the monitor in power save mode it won't come back, or does this happen while you are in the middle of using it?

Comment: no the pc just stops working - in the middle of using it

Comment: Check the `dmesg` command, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.